# Laravel Spark installation issue - dont download spark forbidden access

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have a Laravel Spark Account with a token registred.

I have install laravel spark installer but failed to create a new project.

When i launch the command `spark new myproject`

I have this :

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

Application ready! Build something amazing.

Downloading Spark...


In RequestException.php line 113:

  Client error: GET https://spark.laravel.com/api/releases/7.0.0/download?api_token=vFhBeFakargKjmIoVT4w8JEkajHsenk2W69wyg3qJ0C6   wcTNH6VqxrXWf17t resulted in a 403 Forbidden response:

  {

      "message": ""

  }

new [--braintree] [--team-billing] [--] <name>
```

The token referenced has been checked.

Why doesn't it allow me to download Laravel Spark?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, generate a new token. I'm pretty sure you've pasted your real token (hopefully not) which could be used by anyone reading this...

Go here and delete/recreate a fresh token as soon as possible

```
https://spark.laravel.com/settings#/api
```

---

If that error doesn't actually contain your real token, you can check what token you are using by doing:

```
$ spark token
```

This should spit out your current token. In the error you pasted, the token looks like it has a lot of space in it, which won't work. See if `$ spark token` shows the same spaces. It shouldn't... If it does, set your token again (with no spaces!)

```
$ spark register your-token-here
```

If this still doesn't work, remember that spark is a paid service. Utilize the support they offer and hopefully you'll get a response back quickly